# python can't send attachment files through email

Tags: python, email

I have the following code which works fine, but it doesn't send the attachment files.

```
import smtplib
import os
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.MIMEBase import MIMEBase
from email import Encoders

msg=MIMEMultipart()

def mymail(address,body,format,mylist=None):

    msg['To']=address
    msg['From']='ggous1@gmail.com'
    if format=='txt':
        text_msg=MIMEText(body,'plain')
    elif format=='html':
        text_msg=MIMEText(body,'html')
    msg.attach(text_msg)
    if mylist is not None:
        mylist=[]
        fn=[]
        for f in range(len(mylist)):
            direct=os.getcwd()
            os.chdir(direct)
            part=MIMEBase('application','octet-stream')
            part.set_payload(open(mylist[f],'rb').read())
            Encoders.encode_base64(part)
            part.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="%s"' % os.path.basename(mylist[f])) 
            fn.append(part)
            msg.attach(fn)

    srv=smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com')
    srv.set_debuglevel(1)
    srv.ehlo()
    srv.starttls()
    srv.ehlo()
    srv.login('username','pass')
    srv.sendmail(msg['From'],msg['To'],msg.as_string())
    srv.quit()

if __name__=="__main__":
    address=raw_input('Enter an address to send email in the form "name@host.com" ')
    body=raw_input('Enter the contents of the email')
    format=raw_input('The format is txt or html?')
    question=raw_input('Do you have any files to attach?Yes or No?')
    mylist=[]
    if question=='Yes' or question=='yes':
        fn=raw_input('Enter filename')
        mylist.append(fn)

    mymail(address,body,format,mylist)
```

Am I not using MIMEBase right, or do I have an error in my code?

UPDATE------------------------

```
 if mylist is not None:
        mylist=[]
        fn=[]
        for f in range(len(mylist)):
            direct=os.getcwd()
            os.chdir(direct)
            fn[f]=open(mylist[f],'r')             
            part=msg.attach(MIMEApplication(fn[f]))
            mylist.append(part)
```

Comment: Also, you could (should) just check **'if mylist:'** instead of an explicit comparison.  **'if mylist:'** will return **False** if it is 'None' or an empty list, dictionary, string, etc.  Also consider using **"if question.lower() == 'yes':"**

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I would recommend to use [MIMEApplication](http://docs.python.org/library/email.mime.html#email.mime.application.MIMEApplication%20MIMEApplication) instead for the attachment. You also do not need to do all the payload encoding manually since that is already done automatically. This example works for me:

```
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.application import MIMEApplication
from email.utils import formataddr
from email.utils import make_msgid
from email.utils import formatdate

email = MIMEMultipart()
email['From'] = formataddr(('Jane Doe', 'jane@example.com'))
email['Subject'] = u'Test email'
email['Message-Id'] = make_msgid()
email['Date'] = formatdate(localtime=True)
email.attach(MIMEText(u'This is your email contents.'))
email.attach(MIMEApplication('your binary data'))
print email.as_string()
```

Note that I'm also taking care to set a proper Date and Message-Id header here.

Applying that to your code (and doing a few small cleanups) I get the following working code:

```
import smtplib
import os
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.application import MIMEApplication
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.utils import make_msgid
from email.utils import formatdate


def make_mail(address,body,format,mylist=[]):
    msg = MIMEMultipart()
    msg['To'] = address
    msg['From'] = 'ggous1@gmail.com'
    msg['Message-Id'] = make_msgid()
    msg['Date'] = formatdate(localtime=True)
    msg.attach(MIMEText(body, 'plain' if format == 'txt' else 'html'))
    for filename in mylist:
        part = MIMEApplication(open(filename).read())
        part.add_header('Content-Disposition',
                'attachment; filename="%s"' % os.path.basename(filename))
        msg.attach(part)
    return msg    

def send_mail(msg):
    srv = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com')
    srv.set_debuglevel(1)
    srv.ehlo()
    srv.starttls()
    srv.ehlo()
    srv.login('username','pass')
    srv.sendmail(msg['From'], msg['To'], msg.as_string())
    srv.quit()

if __name__=="__main__":
    address=raw_input('Enter an address to send email in the form "name@host.com" ')
    body=raw_input('Enter the contents of the email')
    format=raw_input('The format is txt or html?')
    question=raw_input('Do you have any files to attach?Yes or No?')
    mylist=[]
    if question=='Yes' or question=='yes':
        fn=raw_input('Enter filename')
        mylist.append(fn)

    msg = make_mail(address,body,format,mylist)
    send_mail(msg)
```

Comment: :Hello, i dis as you said,but still the same.I updated.Thanks!

Comment: I've added a cleaned up version if your original code, which works for me.

Comment: :Ok, it worked!Thanks!But i can't understand this.If i leave mylist=None in the function and do inside the function 'if mylist is not None' then it doesn't send the file!

Comment: look carefully at your code: you test if is not None, but in the very next line you do mylist=[].

Comment: :Ok, i am doing this now but still the same! "mylist=[] ",then " for filename in mylist: part=...... " .I want to keep mylist=None as an argument to the function.How can i handle this?

Comment: You do not need "mylist=[]" at all. Just remove that line.

Comment: Nice :-) i spent an hour with MIMEBase without any success ... then i saw this. Worked like a charm.